# EF Core 2.2 Many-to-Many fetch related list

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, many-to-many, generic-list, ef-core-2.2

I have a Many-to-Many relationship with 3 tables:

```
Products
Categories
ProductCategories
```

How can I fetch or access the **List of Category** (Not list of ProductCategories) by a product?

Comment: you can use dbContext.Categories.ToList()? or maybe you mean something else?

Comment: I have product object, I need to fetch List<Category> of the product.

Comment: when you get product object you should `Inculde` the `ProductCategories`and `ThenInclude` the Categories and finally your Product object have a `Categories, am I right understand?

Comment: Thanks, I did that, my Product object includes a List<ProductCategory> which each one has a Category, but I need to extract a List<Category> to pass to a method

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem and I solved it through returning JSON_QUERY

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [Account].[GetByProduct]
    @ProductId
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        P.*,
        PC.*
        JSON_QUERY((
            SELECT 
                C.*
            FOR JSON PATH
        )) AS [Categories]
    FROM 
        [Relation] AS R
        INNER JOIN [Product] AS P
        ON P.[Id] = R.[ProductRef]
        INNER JOIN [ProductCategory] AS PC
        ON PC.[Id] = R.[ProductCategoryRef]
        INNER JOIN [Category] AS C
        ON C.[Id] = AR.[CategoryRef]
    WHERE
        P.[Id] = @ProductId
END
```

Note: I'd rename the columns&tables to use singular, not plural.

On EF Core side, you'll have to apply a [conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions) using JSON to List.

Answer (score 0):

Use this one I think its helpful:

```
var result = (from pc in ProductCategories
               join c in Categories on pc.CategoryId equals c.CategoryId 
               join p in Products on pc.ProductId equals p.ProductId 
               select new Category { //any selector you need in Category }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Include()` and `ThenInclude()` to [load related data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data?view=aspnetcore-2.1).

For example, if I have models like

```
 public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ProductCategory> ProductCategories { get; set; } = new List<ProductCategory>();
}

public class Category
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ProductCategory> ProductCategories { get; set; } = new List<ProductCategory>();

}
public class ProductCategory
{
    [Key]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }

    [Key]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

Access the list of Category by a product

```
//select specific product whose Id is 1 
var product = await _context.Products.Include(p => p.ProductCategories)
                                              .ThenInclude(pc => pc.Category)
                                              .FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Id == 1);


var categories = product.ProductCategories.Select(pc => pc.Category).ToList();
```